# How to run Jquery constructor from own function?

Tags: jquery, function, object

I need to create a function which will returning jQuery.Color object and i have no idea how to do it. Here is code example

```
function newcolor () { var obj =  new $.Color( 'rgb(0,0,0)' ); return obj;}

var foo = newcolor();

foo.red();
```

Edit:

My full code:

```
function my (element,a,b,c){ //class my
   this.target = $(elem);
   this.new_color = function (a,b,c) { return new $.Color( 'rgb('+a+','+b+','+c+')'); }
   this.base_color = new_color (a,b,c);
   this.colorize = function () ( this.target.css({ background-color: new_color });
}

var div = new My($('foo'),0,0,0);
div.new_color(255,255,255);
div.colorize();
```

My goal is to create class which can hold jquery element and operate on it. Now I'm stuck on returning $.Color().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
function My(elem,r,g,b){ //class my

  this.setColor = function(r,g,b) {
    this.r = (r || 0);
    this.g = (g || 0);
    this.b = (b || 0);
  };

  this.colorArray = function() {
    return [this.r, this.g, this.b];
  };

  this.colorString = function() {
    return "rgb(" + this.colorArray().join(",") + ")";
  };

  this.colorize = function(r,g,b) {
    if (r && g && b) {
      this.setColor(r,g,b);
    }
    var color = $.Color(this.colorString());
    this.target.css({backgroundColor: color});
  }

  // initialize
  this.target = $(elem);
  this.setColor(r,g,b);
  this.colorize();
};

var div1 = new My($('#div1'),100,20,40);
div1.setColor(255,255,200);
div1.colorize();

var div2 = new My($('#div2'),100,20,40);
```

You'll notice that I've basically added some wrapper functions and just stored the separate r,g,b values for the instance.  Then you only call j1Query.Color method at the last minute when you need it.  Then there's no need to have the color instance lying around.

I've put this on codepen as well:
http://codepen.io/bunnymatic/pen/yLxwp

Comment: You could even take it further by making `setColor` run `colorize` so that everytime you call setColor, the color is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the help and time, I'll try to implement this to my code and see how it works.